# mit "zu" oder ohne, wenn eine Verbalphrase als Subjekt fungiert

Tags: grammar

Zwei Beispielsätze. Es kann aber sein, dass da Fehler bei der Groß- und Kleinschreibung sind.

> kaputte Weblinks Reparieren ist echt anstregend....
>   kaputte Weblinks zu reparieren ist echt anstregend....

Naja, die Frage wäre, ob es einen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen den beiden Fällen gibt. Oder ist es eigentlich das Gleiche?

EDIT: Und welche Variante wäre gebräuchlicher?

Answer (score 5):

Die Bedeutung ist bei beiden Varianten praktisch dieselbe. Die zweite Variante dürfte gebräuchlicher sein.

Comment: Welche Variante wäre häufiger?

Comment: Ich vermute, dass es vom Verb abhängt welche Variante häufiger genutz wird.

Comment: @alk Fallen dir zufälligerweise einige Beispiele dazu ein? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the upper-case "Reparieren", consider rephrasing like this:

> "Das Reparieren von kaputten Weblinks ist echt anstrengend."

Otherwise your first option "Kaputte Weblinks Reparieren..." sounds really strange to my Austrian ears.